# how to update multiple rows in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <?php
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="xxxx"; // Mysql username 
    $password="xxxx"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="xxxx"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="xxxx"; // Table name 

    // Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $sql="SELECT * FROM xxxx WHERE branch = 'xx' AND xxxx.semester=x ORDER BY xxxx.xxxx";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Count table rows 
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    ?>

    <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <tr> 
    <td>
    <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">


    <tr>
    <td align="center"><strong>Id</strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong>may_tc_s1</strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong>may_ac_s1</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    // Check if button name "submit" is active, do this 
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET xxx='$name[$i]', xxx='$lastname[$i]', xxx='$email[$i]' WHERE xxx='$id[$i]'";
    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
    }
    }
    if(isset($result1)){
    header("location:try.php");
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td align="center"><?php $id[]=$rows['idatten']; ?><?php echo $rows['idatten']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><input name="name[]" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $rows['username']; ?>"></td>
    <td align="center"><input name="lastname[]" type="text" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $rows['may_tc_s1']; ?>"></td>
    <td align="center"><input name="email[]" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $rows['may_ac_s1']; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
```

I am able to see the records in the text fields but the new entered 
values are not getting updated?????
Is there any thing wrong with the code?????
Tried with various methods and could'nt find any correct methods???

Comment: a little debugging would go a long way

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code:

```
extract($_POST);
if (isset($Submit)) 
 {
  for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
   {
    $update=("UPDATE tbl_name SET name='$name[$i]', lname='$lastname[$i]',email='$email[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]'");
    $res=mysql_query($update);
   }
 }
 if(isset($res))
  {
   header("location:try.php");
  }
?>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
```

Comment: You have been posting a lot of answers which are not actually answers to the questions being asked.

Answer (score -1):

You are not quoting variables properly.

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET xxx='".$name[$i]."', xxx='".$lastname[$i]."', xxx='".$email[$i]."' WHERE xxx='".$id[$i]."'";
```